# Writing a program

Tags: shell-script

I'm writing a script in Linux and having some trouble with the commands to use in the script file. This is what i'm trying to accomplish:

Finds all of the lines in the file /etc/passwd which contain the phrase “student”

Takes first and the last field of those results.

Sorts the lines alphabetically

Places the sorted lines in the file that the user specified

Comment: so far I've gotten grep student /etc/passwd | cut -c 1;7 > testfile2

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

outfile="${1:-out}"

if [ -e "$outfile" ]; then
    printf 'The filename "%s" already exists, refusing to overwrite\n' "$outfile" >&2
    exit 1
fi

awk -F':' '/student/ { print $1, $NF }' /etc/passwd | LC_ALL=C sort -o "$outfile"
```

This script uses `awk` to parse the `passwd` file.  It skips all lines except for those that contains the string `student`.  For those lines, it will output the first and last `:`-delimited fields.

The output from `awk` is handed to `sort`, which sorts the lines in lexicographical order in the standard POSIX locale and stores the result in a file whose name is given on the command line.

If no filename is given on the command line, a file called `out` will be produced. If the name of the output file already exists, the script exits with an error.

```
$ chmod +x script
$ ./script output
```

The output is to be found in the file named `output` in this example.

As an alternative to the `awk` command:

```
sed '/student/s/\([^:]*\):.*:\(.*\)$/\1 \2/' /etc/passwd | LC_ALL=C sort -o "$outfile"
```

This does the same thing, but by applying a substitution to each line that contains the string `student`.  The substitution will replace the whole line with whatever is before the first `:`, followed by a space, followed by whatever is after the last `:`.

Since the `passwd` format is well known, we know that the last column is column 7.  This means that we can get away with this simple `grep` + `cut` + `tr`, as another alternative:

```
grep -F 'student' /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f1,7 | tr ':' ' ' | LC_ALL=C sort -o "$outfile"
```

The `grep` finds all the lines in the file that we are interested in. `cut` gives us the first and last fields. `tr` will replace the `:` between the two fields with a space character.